# How to use where clause in LINQ to display specific row?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I need to display only the specific row from the xml, specific to the email id of the employee.

By this piece of code I'm returning the list of all the employees.

```
 List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();

                employees = (from rows in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()

                             select new Employee
                             {
                                 EmployeeID = rows[0].ToString(),
                                 Name = rows[1].ToString(),
                                 Email = rows[2].ToString(),
                                 DateOfBirth = rows[3].ToString(),
                                 Country = rows[4].ToString(),
                                 ContactNo = rows[5].ToString(),
                                 EmployeeType = rows[6].ToString(),
                                 Password = rows[7].ToString(),
                                 ConfirmPassword = rows[8].ToString(),
                             }).ToList();
                return employees;
```

How do I put a where condition that should check the xml email node and display the respective row?

Comment: Where is the data from xml in your question ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();

        employees = (from rows in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                     where rows.Email =="your email id"

                     select new Employee
                     {
                         EmployeeID = rows[0].ToString(),
                         Name = rows[1].ToString(),
                         Email = rows[2].ToString(),
                         DateOfBirth = rows[3].ToString(),
                         Country = rows[4].ToString(),
                         ContactNo = rows[5].ToString(),
                         EmployeeType = rows[6].ToString(),
                         Password = rows[7].ToString(),
                         ConfirmPassword = rows[8].ToString(),
                     }).ToList();
        return employees;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
employees = (from rows in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
             where rows[2].ToString() == "email@email.com"
             select new Employee
             {
                 EmployeeID = rows[0].ToString(),
                 Name = rows[1].ToString(),
                 Email = rows[2].ToString(),
                 DateOfBirth = rows[3].ToString(),
                 Country = rows[4].ToString(),
                 ContactNo = rows[5].ToString(),
                 EmployeeType = rows[6].ToString(),
                 Password = rows[7].ToString(),
                 ConfirmPassword = rows[8].ToString(),
             }).ToList();
            return employees;
```

hope this helps.